# Making local copies of my Github and Gitlab Repos

Tags: git, github, backup, gitlab

I have a number of projects stored under my user in both Github and Gitlab cloud repositories.

The Github projects are owned by my github user, and the Gitlab projects are owned by my gitlab user.

The Guthub projects are all public, but the Gitlab projects are a mixture of public and private.

It has come to my attention that I am using an all my eggs in one basket approach and if either Github or Gitlab dispensary from the internet they will take my projects with them.

I would like to know what the best practice approach is for people to create backups of their work that if required can be turned into functioning git repos if online services dissapear.

Is there a script that can automatically clone all git repos based on a specific user? - I guess it would use an API to list out all projects for a particular user than issue the clone commands.
The script would ideally be runnable nightly and would re-fetch recent changes to the repos.

Is a clone the best method? Is extracting some kind of zip or database dump better?

What do other people do?

As a side issue I think I will probably lose Project settings, variables, keys, Issue's, Wiki's, etc. in this process, but I am guessing backing these up would be useless anyway as these will be in proprietary formats and once Github/Gitlab is gone they would be unusable.

Note: My Gitlab projects have their Gitlab CI processes which I presume would not work.

Comment: I don't think this question fits the format of [so] because answers **will** be highly opinionated. I don't think that GitHub **AND** GitLab will cease to exist over night. If you really think this is a possibility, then host a GitLab instance yourself.

Comment: I appreciate your points. This was sparked by a to do list item I created after the gitlab data loss incident. It didn't affect me but it made me think. I am happy with both gitlab and github and use the free tier of both. But as a programmer this is all my work and u do want independent backups in case the worst happens

Comment: While the GitLab downtime was unfortunate, only GitLab specific things were lost (6 hours of work). Repositories were unchaged. As I said, your best bet is probably to host GitLab yourself and deploy backup practices there.

Comment: I suggest running your own GitLab instance and configuring regular backups. [Installation is easy](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) and you have full control.